# Current visitor's info (including adwords keyword data)

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

How can I extract all the information about the current visitor through Analytics API? I'm trying to extract this data in real time (hopefully through a snippet in the footer) and then pass some of it to the contact form.

One of the data points we're trying to extract is the keyword data from Adwords (which is available in our analytics interface).

I looked at using auto-tagging (which returns numeric values) or deciphering the GLID using the Adwords API (but there's gotta be an easier way).

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate, but in short you cannot get information on a specific visitor in realtime because a) there is not identifier for a user accessible via the API and b) you would run into the API limits pretty quickly .

Comment: thank you for the clarification, that makes sense.